# Sticky nav with parallax banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a mock clothing site. I have a parallax banner and a nav below it. What I'm trying to achieve is having the nav stick to the top of the page once the user actually scrolls past the nav. I am able to get the nav to stick to the top of the page, but it does so while still on the banner image.

**Here's the CSS**

```
.banner {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/896291/pexels-photo-896291.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260');
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

nav {
  border-top: solid #000 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 50px 0;
}

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
    border-bottom: solid black 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px dimgray;

}
```

**Here's the jQuery**

```
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
if($(window).scrollTop()) {
    $('nav').addClass('sticky');
} else {
    $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
}
})
```

**[And here's my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2hbqmbo/)** demonstrating the issue.

I've had a few theories on why this is happening.

At first I thought maybe it's happening because my top is set to 0, but when I changed the value it still triggered .sticky, but just floated in the middle of the page.

Then I thought, maybe it was because I attached scrollTop() to window. I tried attaching it to nav like this

```
if($('nav').scrollTop()) {
   //add class
 }
```

and that didn't work either.

Thanks in advance for any insight you guys might have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you will have to check if you the scroll top is bigger then a the value it should be scrolling to the top. If you did that, you should be able to just add a class to that item or remove it.
Example:

```
var slide = $('yourIdOrClassName').offset().top;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() > slide) {
     $('nav').addClass('sticky');
  } else {
  $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
  }
});
```

You will need a class with the property `display: none;` and a class with the property `display: block;`

The property of `display: none;` says that the element will not be shown on the page. `display: block` is the default display property for the nav / div element.

Comment: Ahh thanks, this worked! As you expected I did have to change the value. 500 did the trick :)

Comment: Give your your center element a class. Then just put this code in and check it

Comment: var slide = $('.yourclassname').offset().top;

Comment: this checks if the center element is on the top of the page and with that code it will work on different display sizes :)

Comment: I updated the answer, you can now look it up above :)

Comment: Oh yeah this is definitely a better alternative as opposed to hard coding in a value. Thanks! I've learned a lot :)